# How to prevent a regex match if a certain substring is present within?

Tags: regex, escaping, substring

HTML comments may use inline JavaScript as special blocks for old browsers that don't support  JS code. These blocks look like this:

```
<!--
some js code
//-->
```

I want to distinguish 'true' html comments from such in JS code. I've written this regex:

```
/<!--[^//]*?-->/g
```

So I want to exclude matches with a double slash inside, but the regex regards `//` as a character set of `/` and `/`, not as entire double slash `//`. What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Character classes, as you noted, only match a single character, so you can't use them here. But you can make use of [negative lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/<!--(?:(?!//)[\s\S])*-->/g
```

(assuming this is JavaScript).

**Explanation:**

```
<!--     # Match <!--
(?:      # Try to match...
 (?!//)  #  (asserting that there is no // ahead)
 [\s\S]  #  any character (including newlines)
)*       # ...any number of times.
-->      # Match -->
```